# JS - how to divide value into many inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example super admin assigned me 10 licenses. I want divide those licenses into different users.

**So my input where value is dynamicly obtained from backend looks as follow:**

```
<input type="text" disabled value="10" class="license_number">
```

And then i want to divide those licenses to users i want to.

USER1

```
...

<input type="text" disabled value="" class="user_license">

...
```

USER2

```
...

<input type="text" disabled value="" class="user_license">

...
```

So together in every user_license input there can be as much licenses as i get from superadmin.

Now i can assign either 10 licenses to USER1 or 6 to USER1 and 4 to USER2 and so on...therefore i want to decrement license_number aaccording to user_license.

Comment: `var al = $(".license_number").val(), ul = 0; $(".user_license").each(function() {ul += $(this).val()}); if(ul != al) alert("invalid assignment!")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple.

First get the value of admin issued license in a variable, then keep updating it when a user license count changes. Then compare with original admin license count.

Although, the below code can be optimized, it will get you started in right direction.

```
var tot_ln = avl_ln = $(".license_number").val(),
    usr_ln = 0; 

$(".user_license").on("change", function() {    // use keyup instead of change if desired
    $(".user_license").each(function() {
        usr_ln += $(this).val()
    });
    if(usr_ln <= tot_ln) {
        avl_ln = tot_ln - usr_ln;
        alert("Remaining: "+avl_ln);
    } else {
        alert("Allotted more licenses than available");
    }
});
```